# How do I get the default mail client using applescript?

Tags: email, client, applescript

Can anyone please tell me, how do I get the default mail client using applescript?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found part of this code [here](http://macscripter.net/viewtopic.php?pid=131228), ran it on Snow Leopard (10.6.4), and it worked for me.

```
on run
    set mailClient to getDefaultMailClient()   -- store application id
    tell application id mailClient to activate -- tell mail client to do something
end run

-- Grab id of default mail client
on getDefaultMailClient()
    set prefPath to (path to preferences as text) & "com.apple.LaunchServices.plist"
    tell application "System Events"
        try
            value of property list item "LSHandlerRoleAll" of ¬
                (first property list item of property list item "LSHandlers" of ¬
                 property list file prefPath whose value of property list items ¬
                 contains "mailto")
            on error
                "com.apple.mail"
        end try
    end tell
end getDefaultMailClient
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option: `VERSIONER_PERL_PREFER_32_BIT=1 perl -MMac::InternetConfig -le 'print +(GetICHelper "mailto")[1]'`

Answer (score -1):

there has been a discussion on this toppic in the [macscripter-forum](http://macscripter.net/viewtopic.php?pid=131228) 
there you find also some code examples on how test for the default mail-client