# how to get default mail client version on mac os x?

Tags: objective-c, c, macos, system-information

I am new here. I have searched about default mail client information on mac os x.
I found some help here
[How do I get the default mail client using applescript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3986512/how-do-i-get-the-default-mail-client-using-applescript)
But i did not got all the information i wanted.I got default mail client name but could not got its version that i see in "About Mail" section of Mail.app(when launched).

Comment: Show us what you've tried so far.

Comment: I,ve searched so far and i got some references from internet but they were only GUI based techniques to view version of my default mail client.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[LaunchServices](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Carbon/Conceptual/LaunchServicesConcepts/LSCTasks/LSCTasks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30000999-CH203-SW4) is the OS X API that contains info about the user's preferred applications.

The [`LSGetApplicationForURL()` function](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Carbon/Reference/LaunchServicesReference/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/LSGetApplicationForURL) will return the data you seek. Here's a short example of its use:

```
#include <CoreFoundation/CoreFoundation.h>
#include <ApplicationServices/ApplicationServices.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  CFURLRef mailURL = CFURLCreateWithString(kCFAllocatorDefault, CFSTR("mailto://"), NULL);
  CFURLRef mailAppURL = NULL;
  OSStatus ret = 0;
  if((ret = LSGetApplicationForURL(mailURL, kLSRolesAll, NULL, &mailAppURL)) == 0)
  {
    CFStringRef path = CFURLCopyFileSystemPath(mailAppURL, kCFURLPOSIXPathStyle);
    CFShow(path);

    CFRelease(path);
    CFRelease(mailAppURL);
  }
  else
  {
    fprintf(stderr, "LaunchServices error %d\n", ret);
  }

  CFRelease(mailURL);
  return ret;
}
```

On my system, that prints `/Applications/Mail.app`. If you want more info about the returned item, you can use the [`LSCopyItemInfoForURL()` function](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Carbon/Reference/LaunchServicesReference/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/LSCopyItemInfoForURL) on `mailAppURL`.