# Mac OS Framework header file MachineExceptions.h error : declaration does not declare anything

Tags: ios, macos, launch-services

**Background**

I'm trying to use the `LSGetApplicationForURL` API and found a very useful example here - [how to get default mail client version on mac os x?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15401334/how-to-get-default-mail-client-version-on-mac-os-x/15419160#15419160)

However, when I try to compile the code, I get this error:

> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Frameworks/CarbonCore.framework/Headers/MachineExceptions.h:53:
>   error: declaration does not declare anything

When I opened up MachineExceptions around line 53, this is where I saw some declarations of `unsignedwide`, which is a type that is defined in `MacTypes.h`. I found out this was part of the Carbon Core framework.

For starters, I am only including the top-level headers in my code (in fact, using the exact sample code found in the example above). So, I'm not including / touching `MachineException.h` or any of the other header files. Although, obviously there seems to be some dependencies that eventually lead to this error.

Some of the things I've tried / researched:

1. I found out that Carbon Core has been deprecated in 10.8 (the version I'm using)- https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#releasenotes/General/CarbonCoreDeprecations/ 
   As a result, the `MacTypes.h` in the Carbon Core framework was rather anaemic, which conditionally included `MacTypes.h` from /usr/include/
2. I've tried editing `MacTypes.h` (in the Carbon Core framework) and MachineExceptions.h to include MacTypes from /usr/include, per the information on the 'deprecated' page above.
3. Switched around the order of including the header files (worked for someone else while I was researching this).
4. I am including the CoreFoundation and ApplicationServices frameworks in my makefile (using the '-framework' option)

Any feedback on this issue is greatly appreciated as I've spent many hours trying to sort this out. I apologize in advance if anything in here is fundamental / basic. I am very new to Mac OS programming and trying to understand how Frameworks are wired, also how to use them.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you get seems like the result of some macro definition. Do you have `LR` macro defined somewhere in your code or in preprocessor definitions in your project? Take a look at note in the line 42 of MachineExceptions.h about `CR`. Looks like you have something similar.

Anyway I've successfully compiled the code in example with default command line tool project. So probably error in your project configuration.

Comment: Spot on, Cody!  I did have a conflicting symbol in my makefile.  Cleaned that up and got a successful compile.  Thanks for your help!!