# Detect default browser in Applescript

Tags: browser, applescript

Since I changed my default web browser quite often in recent times, I was wondering if there was a way to specifically address your default browser. I could only find a [10 year old Stackoverflow-post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3986512/how-do-i-get-the-default-mail-client-using-applescript) that mentioned to do a similar thing with the current mail client but I didn't find anything about the default browser. I suppose there is a similar way of doing this with default browser, but I don't really understand the code of the accepted answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For some time now in **macOS**, the **~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.LaunchServices/com.apple.launchservices.secure.plist** *file* contains information about the *default browser* for **URLs** with **HTTP** and **HTTPS** protocols.

The following *example* **AppleScript** *code* parses that file for **http;** and **https;** and provides some, not all, *logic* to do what you want based on what's returned. As coded it favors both being set to the same *value* and if not, you'll need to add additional *logic* to suite that scenario.

```
set defaultBrowserList to paragraphs of (do shell script "defaults read \\
    ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.LaunchServices/com.apple.launchservices.secure \\
    | awk -F'\"' '/http;|https;/{print window[(NR)-1]}{window[NR]=$2}'")

if (count defaultBrowserList) is not equal to 2 then return

if item 1 of defaultBrowserList is equal to item 2 of defaultBrowserList then
    set defaultBrowser to item 1 of defaultBrowserList
else
    return
end if

if defaultBrowser is "" or defaultBrowser contains "safari" then
    --  # The default Browser is Safari.
    set defaultBrowser to "Safari"
    --  # Your code goes here.
else if defaultBrowser contains "chrome" then
    --  # The default Browser is Google Chrome.
    set defaultBrowser to "Google Chrome"
    --  # Your code goes here.
else if defaultBrowser contains "firefox" then
    --  # The default Browser is Firefox.
    set defaultBrowser to "Firefox"
    --  # Your code goes here.
else
    set defaultBrowser to "Other"
    --  # Your code goes here.
end if
```

---

**Notes:**

The start of the `if defaultBrowser` *statement* tests for nothing `""` as well as `"safari"`, because, if **Safari** is the only *Browser* installed or if another *Browser* is installed and has never had a default *Browser* set, then by default nothing will be returned by the `do shell script "defaults ..."` *command*, and this means **Safari** is the default *Browser*.

In the *example* **AppleScript** *code* above, the *value* of the `defaultBrowser` *variable* initially gets set to one of the following *values*:

- Nothing: `""`
- `com.apple.safari`
- `com.google.chrome`
- `org.mozilla.firefox`
- Some other: `output`

Then within the `if` *statement*, the `defaultBrowser` gets set to the proper name of the *Browser*. Although you can certainly modify as needed/wanted.

The *example* **AppleScript** *code*, shown above, was tested in **Script Editor** under **macOS Catalina** with **Language & Region** settings in **System Preferences** set to **English (US) — Primary** and worked for me without issue<sup>1</sup>.

- <sup>1</sup>  <sub>Assumes necessary and appropriate setting in **System Preferences** > **Security & Privacy** > **Privacy** have been set/addressed as needed.</sub>

---

For pre **OS X 10.10, replace:**

```
~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.LaunchServices/com.apple.launchservices.secure
```

With:

```
com.apple.LaunchServices
```

In the `do shell script "defaults ..."` *command*.

---

<sub>Note: The *example* **AppleScript** *code* is just that and sans any included *error handling* does not contain any additional *error handling* as may be appropriate. The onus is upon the user to add any *error handling* as may be appropriate, needed or wanted. Have a look at the [**try**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_control_statements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH6g-129232) *statement* and [**error**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_control_statements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH6g-129657) *statement* in the [**AppleScript Language Guide**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/introduction/ASLR_intro.html). See also, [**Working with Errors**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_error_xmpls.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH221-SW1). Additionally, the use of the [**delay**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_cmds.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH216-SW10) *command* may be necessary between events where appropriate, e.g. `delay 0.5`, with the *value* of the *delay* set appropriately.</sub>